# GTK 2 gtk_widget_add_accelerator error: ‘GDK_Z’ undeclared

Tags: c, gtk2, gdk

I'm trying to assign an accelerator to a GTK menu item:

```
group = gtk_accel_group_new();

item = gtk_image_menu_item_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_UNDO, group);

gtk_widget_add_accelerator(item, "activate", group, GDK_Z, GDK_CONTROL_MASK, GTK_ACCEL_VISIBLE);
```

But when I compile I get the following error:

```
./src/main.c:171:55: error: ‘GDK_Z’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   gtk_widget_add_accelerator(item, "activate", group, GDK_Z, GDK_CONTROL_MASK, GTK_ACCEL_VISIBLE);
                                                       ^
```

This is the output from `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`:

```
-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2
```

How can I make the `GDK_Z` identifier available to my program?

Comment: Do you have development package for GTK+ (`libgtk2.0-dev`) installed correctly?

Comment: Hmm. Interesting thought. I tried `sudo apt-get remove libgtk2.0-dev --purge` and then a reinstall `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`. Same problem..

Comment: I am not sure if I have idea about what I am going to say, but does that work if you do `guint key = GDK_z;` or `guint key = GDK_Z;`and then =>> `gtk_widget_add_accelerator(item, "activate", group, key, GDK_CONTROL_MASK, GTK_ACCEL_VISIBLE);
` ?

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried both, same error. These are the reference docs for `gtk_widget_add_accelerator`, they speak of `accel_key` to be `GDK keyval of the accelerator` but I can't find any docs for those. I got the `GDK_Z` example from a GTK 2 book that was popular back in the day. But no reference in there to include anything specific. https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-add-accelerator

Comment: The only thing which I found related to this , [Is This](https://github.com/genesi/gtk2/blob/master/modules/input/imipa.c).

Comment: Thank you! And `#include <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>` it is. If you add it as an answer I will accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not included `gdkkeysyms.h`:

```
#include <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>
```

Which contains `GDK_Z` needed for your program.